# Repository Creation Failed (GitKraken)

Tags: git, repo, gitkraken

I have project files for 3 projects on my laptop. I want to create remote repo for 3rd project, as I've already created local repo.  It is giving the error as seen in the attached image file. When I click "Create remote and push local refs", the error "Failed to create repository. Repository creation failed." occurs. Please let me know of the solution for this.

I initialized 2 repositories yesterday locally, added files and committed to these, then created remote repos for them and pushed local files to remote repo.
I did this now for my 3rd project, which is in xampp's htdocs folder, but it is not working. I've tried searching online but the error message is not very specific so can't find help.

I was expecting it to work just like it did yesterday

[pic of the error on GitKraken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MU1pC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

I had a remote repo made by name of shopping-cart-system which I made by mistake. I was trying to create another by Shopping Cart System which I thought would be a different name, but it maps to the same name with lowercase letters and hyphens.

GitKraken should mention the error explicitly though.